# Firebase websocket protocol, am I missing something?

Tags: firebase, nest-api

I am working on an experimental c# nest client using websockets on an embeded
hardware. My problem is that nest doesn't seem to want to communicate with me
after the initial handshake.

**wss://developer-api.nest.com/.es?v=5 HTTP1.1**

wssClient | Handshake header: Upgrade: websocket
   wssClient | Handshake header: Connection: Upgrade
   wssClient | Handshake header: Sec-WebSocket-Accept: 2TSbkk9Kv0soMbpA0fGrtQUWoyI=
   wssClient | Handshake header: 
   wssClient | Expected sec key: 2TSbkk9Kv0soMbpA0fGrtQUWoyI=
   wssClient | Response sec key: 2TSbkk9Kv0soMbpA0fGrtQUWoyI=
   wssClient | Connected
    nest-cli | connection state changed: Connected
   wssClient | Text frame received: 81 7E 00 95  ..
    nest-cli | < **{"t":"c","d":{"t":"h","d":{"ts":1422883899173,"v":"5","h":"firebase-apiserver03-tah01-iad01.dapi.production.nest.com:9553","s":"session-425920698"}}}**
    nest-cli | > **{"t":"d","d":{"r":1,"a":"auth","b":{"cred":"c.R...MK0"}}}**
   wssClient | Sending data frame: 81 7E 00 C2 ...

after the client sends the credential frame (just like the Firebase.js client) I get no reply from nest ..
no redirection nor confirmation of authentication

is this behavior deliberate (somehow detects that its peer is not firebase) 
or I am doing something wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: I don't have knowledge of the Nest servers, but for regular Firebase instances, you don't initially connect to the host, but just a load balancing array. I'm fairly certain that this line is telling you which host to connect to:  `{"t":"c","d":{"t":"h","d":{"ts":1422883899173,"v":"5","h":"firebase-apiserver03-tah01-iad01.dapi.production.nest.com:9553","s":"session-425920698"}}}` and that this is the server hosting your instance. You probably need to try your auth/etc against that URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered my mistake the next day.
The frames that are sent need to be
masked.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.3

also.., a couple of headers are needed but I don't know exactly which ones (yet) 
I'll update my answer when I do.